# How to solve WGET which cannot connect

Tags: batch-file, wget

I use `WGET` and batch command to download files. My batch script is :

**Download.bat**

```
wget http://abc_server1.com/file1.zip
wget http://abc_server2.com/file2.zip
wget http://abc_server3.com/file3.zip
```

Sometime `wget` cannot connect to one of servers (example: `wget` cannot connect to `server2`). if `wget` not connected to `server 2`, proccess of batch script will stop until `wget` connected. so, `line 3 (wget http://abc_server3.com/file3.zip)` not executed. 
how to solve this problem? Thank for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

From `wget --help`:

```
Download:
  -t,  --tries=NUMBER            set number of retries to NUMBER (0 unlimits).
       --retry-connrefused       retry even if connection is refused.
```

Try setting a number of retries.